# How do you calculate taxes on proceeds from sale of a private company held in escrow?

Tags: united-states, stocks, income-tax, private-company

In 2023, a private company in which I held stock was sold in an all-cash acquisition.  A portion of my proceeds were placed into an escrow account to cover post-sale price adjustments, expenses, and indemnification.

- I received most of the proceeds in mid-2023
- In late 2023, a purchase price adjustment was made.  A portion of the adjustment escrow was returned to the buyer, and I received a payment for the remainder of the escrow deposit plus a small amount of interest.
- The indemnification escrow account is scheduled to be released in 2024, but I can't be certain of exactly how much I'll receive.  It has also earned a small amount of interest credited to the escrow account in both 2023 and 2024.
- I received a 1099-B that reflects the amounts actually received in 2023 (ie the initial payment + the adjustment escrow disbursement, but not the amounts remaining in escrow, nor the amount deducted in adjustment).
- The sale qualifies for a 100% Section 1202 QSBS Exclusion on my federal taxes, but as a California resident, I must add the gains back in to state taxes.

How do I report these transactions?  From what I've seen, this would normally be treated as an installment sale, although it is possible to elect to recognize the full gain in a single year.  Given the QSBS Exclusion and relatively small amount in escrow, it seems like opting out of installment treatment could simplify reporting at the cost of a few bucks of undeferred state tax.

If reported as an installment sale, how do I handle the QSBS treatment?  Should I opt out of installment treatment, how would I handle a later reduction in the escrowed amount I ultimately receive?